# My site redirects to a whole other site

Tags: wordpress, redirect

The main page on my site is being redirected to `www.example.com`, all other pages are fine.

I tried to redirect my site from `www.example.com` to `example.com`.

I didn't know I had to change `example` to my site name, now it doesn't work.

I deleted the code in `.htaccess` file, but it is still redirecting to `example.com`.

I think the following is what was in the deleted `.htaccess` file.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
# index.php to /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*index\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Why is my site being redirected even after deleting this file?

Comment: A little more information would be helpful. Did you grep your code for example.com to see if it exists anywhere else?

Comment: dont know what you mean by grep i gave all the information i can give what type of information do you need. its just my homepage url that redirects to example.com but when im logged in with wordpress it works fine my site is watchmoviesonlinenow.org

Comment: i checked another computer and it showed a blank url as my homepage which was my problem in the first place think you can help with that all other pages work though, my homepage for my website only shows when im logged in to wordpress

Comment: Sorry I wasn't being clear. By 'grep' what I meant was did you do a search through all of your code to check if you have 'example.com' anywhere in there. <br/> Is this a hosted Wordpress site or something you are self hosting?

Comment: thats fine now, my problem now is when i type in my url my homepage shows up blank any help for that

Comment: Without more data there is nothing anyone can do. Can you post the URL here so people can look at it?